# Removing heading in Dresden beamer theme and adding a background

Tags: beamer, graphics, header-footer, backgrounds

Following several example, I success in removing headline and footline for my first frame. However, I tried to use a background image and unfortunately with the Dresden theme (and others maybe) a white stripe remain at the top.

[image: First page whith white stripe]

Here is the code I'm using. This code is working with the Madrid theme, the background image covers the frame.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{movie15}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\title[]{title}
    \author[] {Name}
\institute[INST]{INST}
\date[21 octobre 2013] {21 octobre 2013}


\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{background} {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{background.png}}



\frame{
        \titlepage
       }
}

\end{document}
```

Any idea to remove this white strip and fully frame the background image with Dresden theme?

Answer (score 2):

## Long answer

The problem is within the outer theme called "miniframes". A lot of themes are a specific combination of a color theme and an outer theme. For the Dresden theme you can see it in the `beamerthemeDresden.sty` file (can be easily found online).

Looking at `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty` reveals, that the problem are various vertical spaces in the headline (`vskip` and the `ht` and `dp` options)

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

As you noticed, even changing the headline for the title page does not remove those spaces.

One workaround would be to clear the headline before `\begin{document}` and set the miniframes headline again after the title page. The only problem I have here, is that the theme has a subsection option (show an additional line in the header) and I don't know how to process this within the document. So the easiest is to comment out the `\if...` and `\fi` or the part in between, depending on whether you want the subsection in the headline or not.

**EDIT:**

Apparently the frame title is misplaced if you do this, so this is far from being the optimal solution. To fix this, you can add

```
 \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace{4.5ex}\hspace{-2.7ex}\insertframetitle }
```

(personally, I think that is a little too much tinkering, but it does the job. I just fear that other objects might cause trouble too.)

## Short answer

Make the indicated changes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{movie15}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\title[]{title}
    \author[] {Name}
\institute[INST]{INST}
\date[21 octobre 2013] {21 octobre 2013}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%-------------add------------------
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%----------------------------------
\begin{document}

 {
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{background}         
   {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{background.png}}
  \frame{
    \titlepage
  }
 }

%------------add------------------------------
 \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace{4.5ex}\hspace{-2.7ex}\insertframetitle }

 \setbeamertemplate{headline}
 {%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
   \end{beamercolorbox}
   \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
     \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
 % \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
     \end{beamercolorbox}
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
       leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
       \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
     \end{beamercolorbox}%
 %  \fi%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
   \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
%-------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works for the first page. Now, another problem comes from other frames : if I want to use a frame title, the title is placed into the header.

Comment: that is not good :(

Comment: I did a edit to fix it, if you need to use that theme and are having time pressure, but overall I don't really like the solution.

Comment: It works, thank you !

I don't have time presure, but I try to understand what I'm doing with beamer and since I'm a very beginer it's quite hard to understand specificities of each beamer theme.

Comment: The best is to look into those theme files (http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/)[here]. There are basically color schemes, outer themes (for things like the header and footer), inner themes (for boxes, bullet points,...) and font schemes. The theme-theme you pick (like Dresden) is just a specific combination of these. If you learn some of the variable names and commands you can make your own theme quite easily.